# number of movies for each genre using dict python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, collections, counter

In my code I am trying to find out how many movies are there for each genre in a movie data set. found this as a example but I am not able to find the explanation for this sample code.

```
from collections import Counter

 flattened_genres = [item for sublist in movies_df.genres_arr for item in 
sublist]

genre_dict = dict(Counter(flattened_genres))

print genre_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat difficult to provide all the details without knowing exactly what is in the `movies_df` data set. But... my best guess is that it is an array of movie genres stored in sublists. For this example we can probably consider it to be like a list of lists:

```
[[romance, horror, thriller],
 [action, adventure, mystery],
 [horror, thriller, action],
 [romance, adventure, mystery]]
```

This following line imports the `Counter` class from the `collections` library. The `Counter` class takes a sequence of items and counts how many of each item appears. It stores that data in an `Counter` object that is very much like a dictionary with some extra capabilities (such as the ability to show you which items are most common).

```
from collections import Counter
```

This next bit digs into each of the sublists in the genres array and extracts each of the items from each sublist and dumps them into a single giant list. This is done using a syntax called a list comprehension. This technique of extracting data from nested sublists into a single list is called flattening.

```
flattened_genres = [item for sublist in movies_df.genres_arr for item in sublist]
```

An alternate way of writing the above would be to use nested for loops and append data to the master list:

```
flattened_genres = []
for sublist in movies_df.genres_arr:
    for item in sublist:
        flattened_genres.append(item)
```

List comprehensions often have better performance under the hood than nested for loops and append function calls, but are often a bit harder for beginners to wrap their head around, until they have seen them a few times.

The flattened result looks something like this:

```
[romance, horror, thriller, action, adventure, mystery, horror, thriller, action, romance, adventure, mystery]
```

Any sequence can be fed into a `Counter` to get the counts. Using this simple list, we can count all the 'a's and all the 'b's, etc.

```
c = Counter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'])
```

This produced a `Counter` object that looks like this and shows that it counted two 'a's and two 'b's, etc:

```
>>> c
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

`Counter` objects are a bit different than `dict`s, so if you really needed a dictionary, you can convert the `Counter` to a dictionary by running it through the `dict` factory function to do the conversion. In this case, we are providing the `flattened_genres` `list` as an argument to the `Counter` class inside the `dict` factory function.

```
genre_dict = dict(Counter(flattened_genres))
```

And lastly, we print the new dictionary. This `print` statement is used in Python 2. The Python version 3 `print()` function is provided for completeness:

```
print genre_dict
print(genre_dict)   # for those using Python 3
```